# The ways of uploading files to Telegram Server

Tags: file, upload, telegram, telegram-bot

As I can see currently there is exist only one way to upload any file to the Telegram server throw the TelegramBotApi. (like [SendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto))

My **goal** is to upload any file, save the id from a gotten response and post this file some later to another channel.

**For now**, I have created a private channel to store all files that will be sent in the future.

The **question** is: is there a ways of uploading files to Telegram Server without  "storage channel" i.e. directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is: is there a ways of uploading files to Telegram Server without "storage channel" i.e. directly.

No, currently there's no alternative to your solution. You should either send a file to user or a to channel and then store a `file_id` from response to use it later.

And since [Telegram Bot API states that](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#sending-files)

> `file_id` is unique for each individual bot and can't be transferred from one bot to another.

, this action cannot be automated by another bot.